# DRF how to create dublicate(copy) of instance endpoint?

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

**My models:**

```
class Book(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, models.CASCADE, related_name="books")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

**My view:**

```
class BooksViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin,
                       mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                       mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
                       viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = BookSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Book.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)


   @action(methods=['POST'], detail=False)
   def dublicate(self, *args, **kwargs):
       obj = Book.objects.get(pk=1)
       obj.pk = None
       obj.save()
```

My idea is I want to use `@action` to dublicate some Book objects by id, with all info that Book model have just copy it. How to do it in a right way?

**UPDATE**
I check in docs how to make a copy, but how I can choose pk?

Comment: Um, why do want to duplicate your data?

Comment: @ruddra just need this case. and wanna know how todo it

Answer (score 1):

Something like this,

```
from rest_framework.response import Response


class BooksViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin,
                   mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                   mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
                   viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = BookSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Book.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)

    @action(methods=['POST'], detail=True)
    def duplicate(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        book_instance = self.get_object()
        book_instance.pk = book_instance.id = None
        book_instance.save()
        return Response(self.serializer_class(book_instance).data)
```

Now, send HTTP POST request to `/endpoint/to/book/1234/duplicate` where the `1234` is the PK of `Book` instance that you want to make the copy of.

Comment: thank you! now it's clear for me. One more question how to copy also FK of this model object?

Comment: Then, this is *not a simple* action. You can attach any arbitrary information to the POST payload, which is later accessed via `request.data`

Comment: how can I set it?

Comment: It should be set/attach in the client-side.

Comment: I need to undestand how can I do it from server side

Comment: You can't attach the payload in the server-side